# What are constructors in Java and why should you write your own?

Tags: java, constructor

I don't understand why it is necessary to write your own constructor if the java compiler already does it. What are the reasons for/benefits of writing your own?

This is an example of a constructor in Java:

```
class A{
    
    A(int a){
        
      System.out.println("A");
    
    }

}

class ConstructorDemo1{

    public static void main(String[] args){
    
        A a1 = new A(1000);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried a Java course or article explaining this topic first?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to write a constructor in a class definition, but the compiler will generate a default constructor for you

Comment: Tutorial: [Providing Constructors for your Classes](https://dev.java/learn/classes-objects/defining-constructors/)

Comment: yes I just found out that the java compiler will always write one to create an object, but what are the benefits of writing one yourself?

Comment: Constructors are useful for setting fields within the class. Without them, you'd need to do things like `Something s = new Something(); s.initialize("data", "moreData");`

Comment: @ArianaNelson the constructor is executed when the object is created. So you can define what is supposed to happen at that point in time. It also allows you to specify which explicit superclass constructor is called. It's mostly used to pass values and store them as the class's fields. Think of it as initialization values.

Comment: To ensure that the object is in a consistent state after creation

Comment: The example constructor in your question is a poor example of a constructor because it just throws away the `int a` value which it receives. It would be more useful to save that value to a field in the class (but your class has no fields, either). I don't know, but maybe the too-simple example is leading to you ask your "what's the need?" question.

Comment: @andrewJames I just learned about constructors, I understand the the compiler will always make a constructor whether you write one or not, so I'm wondering whats the point of writing your own.

Comment: @ArianaNelson the compiler only makes the default, empty constructor. In short, it's a standard way to initialize fields rather than to set them individually.

Comment: Maybe a metaphor? If you are baking a cake you can gather all the ingredients up-front (use a constructor); or fetch them one at a time, as you need them (use multiple "setter" methods).

Comment: I just learned that if you write a constructor that takes parameters, it allows you to give your object values at the moment of instantiation rather than after. So this is one example of how it is beneficial, I'm not sure if there are others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

```
class Foo {
   private int a;
   private int b;
   Foo() {}  // only constructor and is created by compiler
   public void setA(int aval) {
      a = aval;
   }
   public void setB(int bval) {
      b = bval;
   }
}
```

Here is how the values would be set for above.

```
Foo foo = new Foo(); // uses default constructor
foo.setA(10);
foo.setB(20);
```

Now add these constructors to the above

```
Foo() {} // must be added manually now since you
         // are adding your own constructor.  If you don't you
         // must use the argument version to create an instance
Foo(int a, int b) {
   a = aval;
   b = bval;
}
```

And create an instance like this.

```
Foo f = new Foo(10,20);  // tada! values are set.
```

You can still initialize the values as in the first example if you included the default constructor.  The setters allow you to also change them at any time.

Not included in the example but you must use `getters` to retrieve the values as they are declared `private`.  Declaring fields private hides implementation details and also allows one to enforce constraints on the fields.